# Certficate Store in Windows "Trusted People" "Trusted Devices"

Tags: ssl, certificate-store

I'm curious when is "Trusted People" and "Trusted Devices" folder used in the Windows Certificate Store. I'm asking because I need to store Leaf (Personal) Certificates of other parties somewhere. This is a desktop application, I don't want to implement some kind of own store, using the Windows Cert Store seems reasonable.

I need to store the Certificate of other parties as kind of a certificate pinning feature. So the TLS connection would only be accepted if the Certificate chain is valid (I trust the root of the sent certificate) and the certificate that I got from the server is also there in either in the "Trusted People" or "Trusted Devices". My only concern is that I don't know what Windows uses these folders for.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is a set of certificates that are implicitly trusted, even without a trusted root signature on them.

It is safer to use than trusting a certificate as a root, since certificates signed by certificates in the Trusted People store won't also be trusted.

Be aware, though, that not all applications are aware of this certificate store, so it's not ideal to rely on it.